# Returning a float value from a function... (C)

Tags: c, function

**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

float aveg(a,b){

        float result;

        result=(a+b)/2;

        return result;
}

int main(void) {

        float a,b,avg;


        printf("first no:  ");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf(" %f\n",a);
        printf("second no: ");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        printf(" %f\n",b);

        avg=(a+b)/2;
        printf("average is:  ");
        printf("%.2f", avg);

        avg=aveg(a,b);
        printf("\n average from function is: ");
        printf("%.2f",avg);
}
```

**This is my output...**

first no:  3
 3.000000
second no: 5
 5.000000
average is:  4.00
 average from function is: 537133056.00

**Can someone explain why I get such a different number from the float function?
I tried declaring the function:**

```
float avg(float a, float b);
```

**But the compiler just got me errors...
Any idea?**

Comment: Different results and compiler errors are two different things. Also, if you get error, please describe them clearly.

Comment: `float aveg(a,b){ /* ... */ }` --> `float aveg(float a, float b){ /* ... */ }`

Comment: 'But the compiler just got me errors' - what errors?

Comment: @hydrz: you should distinguish and show, what are the compilation errors (if you have some), what output your  program if you write the prototype function in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest fix is to add a single dot (will explain in a sec):

```
result=(a+b)/2.;
```

Both `a` and `b` are declared as `int` (by default since you didn't specify any type) so your `(a+b)` results in an integer which is then divided by another integer.

To make the result of your division a float you should make sure at least one operand is of `float` type, which is why the dot in the `2.` (which is just a short version of `2.0`).

The real fix, of course, is to properly declare the data types of your function parameters:

```
float aveg(float a, float b){
```

This will work if you have no other syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Declaring function parameters as `float` didn't fix your code? In what sense?

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you OP? If so, why are you using another account?

Comment: No, your first fix is to add a dot so `2.`

Comment: *"The quickest fix is to add a single dot"*. What works is to declare the arguments as `float`. Changing `2` to `2.` is irrelevant.

Comment: No I am not OP. Anything wrong with compiling OP's code?

Comment: *"`(a+b)` results in an integer"* but the *wrong* integer.

Comment: @WeatherVane adding a dot is a quick fix to get the `float` result of the devision. Please read the post in full - it describes why the dot and how to properly fix the code.

Comment: I don't care what you *say*, adding a dot and nothing else, produces the same wrong result. I compiled and ran it, did you?

Comment: @WeatherVane Your use of "*my* code" in the first comment was misleading. You did not write the code. OP did.

Comment: In fact I did compile and ran. I always do when posting in SO. The result was correct for integer arguments (obviously).

Comment: @ace sorry I should have put "my version of the code".

Comment: OP here, apparetly when I declared float the variables in my function I hada a syntax error somewhere, because it didn't worked back then. Thank you very much, this helped a lot! I've been stuck for a while...

Comment: @YePhIcK without changing the arguments to `float`, as your first paragraph suggests?

Comment: @WeatherVane maybe you should check your dev environment for some other, unrelated issues. The code is a "syntactically correct" code in `C` with the arguments defaulting to `int` data types. it is possible you have a quirk in your compiler that doesn't deal with that properly.

Comment: Perhaps it is MSVC, quel surprise?

Comment: I use MSVC (in fact just to be sure tried on both 2010 and 2015 and even dusted off an old v6). To compile in `C-mode` in MSVC the file has to be of a `.c` extension

Comment: @YePhIcK I suspect it is because the arguments pushed by caller are known to be `float`, but assumed by function to be `int`. MSVC v9.0

Comment: @YePhIcK I've now tried it on MSVC 14.0, same result (from just adding a single `.`). Are you sure you didn't misread the terminal output? It prints the correct `4.00` from the calculation in `main` and then the incorrect function result.

Comment: It would seem I owe you an apology. When I was doing the testing I explicitly defined `int` parameters (was too lazy to change the file name, TBH). Stepping through debugger I clearly see the call pushing 2x`float` on a stack and the function picking up 2x`int` resulting in a wrong calculation. So the MSVC has failed the standard, it would seem? Though I must admit - nobody in clear mind would use an un-typed argument for a function. BTW, declaring the function `float aveg(float a, float b);` before the function's definition does the trick as well.